# Quick and Dirty Playback Settings

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, vlc, rtsp, live555

I'm trying to use VLC to decode and display a H264 video stream from an RTSP-server over a very low bandwidth connection. Doing so VLC manages to establish the RTP stream initially. But after a short while the video freezes and stops, while the following errors are thrown:

```
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 2252 ms)
avcodec error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
live555 warning: no data received in 10s, eof ?
```

These errors disappears when one increases "network-caching" to ~20 s (for obvious reasons). But since this is a live video stream, latency is an issue and increasing network-caching is thus undesirable.

I have however no need for fancy stuff like smooth playback and audio sync that VLC provides by default. A quick and dirty solution where the latest decoded frame is displayed is more than sufficient for me. I know for a fact that this greatly reduces latency using Gstreamer. So I'm looking for a way to do it in VLC. Is it possible to do using setting-flags or do I have to modify the source?

Thanks in advance